# Cant' realy set the Actor's zIndex?

Tags: libgdx

```
public class Character extends Actor {

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {


        int zIndex = 10000 - (int)this.getY();
        if (zIndex < 0) {
            zIndex = 0;
        }

        setZIndex(zIndex);
        System.out.println(zIndex + "\t" + getZIndex());

        batch.draw(currFrame,  getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(),getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());

        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }
}
```

I want set Actor's zIndex by y,

but the result is:

......

9979    999

9980    999

9982    999

9983    999

9983    999

9985    999

9986    999

9986    999

9986    999

.....

Answer (score 0):

oh, I see.

the max value of Actor's zIndex is 999.

Comment: The max value of the `zIndex` is the count of it and its siblings minus 1.